# Как делать многопоточность для парсера?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

К сожалению вопрос коротким не получится. У меня есть представление как работает multithread и async, что такое мьютексы и т.д., но нет понимания как оптимально написать программу, потому что я никак не разберусь когда процессор работает, а когда отдыхает.

Ситуация: Есть парсеры которые работают в сотни потоков. Судя по тому что я знаю про многопоточность, всё что превышает количество ядер процессора получает процессорное время на какой-то небольшой период, после чего ядро переключается на другой поток, обратно и т.д. Допустим моя программа работает через прокси, пропускная способность у них разная, в основном маленькая. Что делают ядра в то время когда через прокси медленно скачивается контент? Имеет ли смысл создавать 100 потоков, или ограничиться 12ю, по кол-ву ядер? Или просто методом наблюдения за скоростью исполнения задач, нагрузкой ядер, подбирать кол-во потоков?

Answer (score 1):

Так как вопрос размытый, ответ будет скорее сборником советов, основанных на многолетнем опыте работы с HPC:

1. Никогда нет смысла делать потоков больше чем ядер, в противном случае будут непродуктивные затраты на переключение потоков.
2. Внутри потока необходимо организовывать менеджмент задач - например, не допускать блокирования потока на операциях c сокетами, а вместо этого загружать его другой работенкой, если она есть.
3. Как можно меньше использовать обращения к операционной системе, например, мьютексы. Больше ипользовать lock-free решения типа facebook/folly

Comment: иногда просто легче создать в два-три раза больше потоков, чем городить систему тасок и другого. Но в любом случае, надо бенчмаркать.

Comment: Конкретная ситуация. У меня есть 100 медленных проксей и 12 ядер. Ширина канала без проксей с лёгкостью эквивалентна пропускной способности 1000 проксей. Я запускаю 12 потоков, какая-то прокся мёртвая, какая-то медленная. Поток занят тем что ожидает необходимый условий чтоб признать проксю нормальной или взять другую. Создавать дополнительный потоки не имеет смысла? Просто я раньше сталкивался с софтом который "работал и в 100 и в 300 потоков" и это вроде было значительно быстрей чем в 10. Ясно что поток=ядро справедливо для работы с локальными файлами. А веб?

Comment: поток=ядро справедливо, если Вы нагружаете его по полной. Если Вы нагружаете на треть, то можно создавать в три раза больше (накладными расходами на переключение пока пренебрегаем). Пока поток висит  на сокете в ожидании порции данных, на него операционная система просто так не будет переключать время. Другое дело, если этих потоков стает 200-300ю Вот тут уже нужно думать и использовать тоже мультиплексирование для сети (select/poll/аналоги). А потоки отдельно для парсинга.